# Deallocating the callback listener object in boost bind when notifier/signal goes out of scope

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, memory-leaks, boost-signals

Am in a situation to hold pointers in a vector just so that I can use them to release the memory in the dtor.

I have an object listening for callbacks(slots) from the boost signals.These objects needed to have a scope larger than the method its being created in as it should be listening to the boost signals emitted much later than where it is created.So, I had to allocate the memory in heap and immediately subscribes to boost signals using that instance.

Now these objects should be deallocated from memory when the class holding the signals are destroyed.Now what are my options,

- Does boost deallocate all these objects when boost signal goes out of scope and all listening boost:bind objects are destroyed??
- Will shared pointer or smart pointer help me in this?
- Do I have to have a vector of all these pointers in the Signaling Service to deallocate in its desctructor?Is there a better way?

  ```
  void methodA(){

  CallbackHandler* cbHandler=new CallbackHandler(..);    //Allocating in heap as we want to receive boost signals on  
                                                         //this instance even after this method exits
  signalingService.subscribeToCertainSignals(signalType,boost::bind(&CallbackHandler::boostSlotListener,cbHandler,_1));
  }


  // Boost Signal -SignalingService
   boost::signal<void (const std::string &msg)> signal1;
   boost::signal<void (const std::string &msg)> signal2;

   void subscribeToCertainSignals(const std::string& signalType,boost::function<void (const std::string& str)> bindObject){
          this->signal1.connect(bindObject);
          this->signal2.connect(bindObject);

   }
   void sendSignals(A a){
       if(check){
          this->signal1("somestring1");
        }else{
          this->signal1("somestring1");
        }
  ```

  };

Comment: I am a java developer just started C++ programming. Started reading a few good C++ books but still trying to find my way. Please advice if something is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this would be to store `shared_ptr`s to all the listeners in the object holding the signals, and `weak_ptr`s to the listeners outside. When the object holding the signals is destructed, the reference count in each of the `shared_ptr`s will go to `0` and the listeners pointed to will be deleted. Now, when you next try and lock the `weak_ptr`s to access the listeners from outside the object holding the signals, the locking will fail because the pointees will have been deleted - this is easy to detect because `lock` will return a null `shared_ptr`.

Here's a concrete example for you (not using Boost.Signals unfortunately, just to illustrate the point):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Listener
{
public:
    virtual ~Listener() {}
    virtual void signal() = 0;
};

class Subject
{
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Listener> > m_listeners;
public:
    void add_listener(const std::shared_ptr<Listener>& listener)
    {
        m_listeners.push_back(listener);
    }

    void signal_all()
    {
        // Note that you could use "auto it = ..." here in C++11.
        for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Listener> >::iterator it=m_listeners.begin(), iend=m_listeners.end(); it!=iend; ++it)
        {
            (*it)->signal();
        }
    }
};

class MyListener : public Listener
{
    void signal()
    {
        std::cout << "Signalled!\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Listener> > listeners;

    {
        Subject s;  

        std::shared_ptr<Listener> listener(new MyListener);
        s.add_listener(listener);
        listeners.push_back(listener);
        listener.reset();

        s.signal_all();

        // Locking the listener yields the listener here.
        std::cout << listeners[0].lock() << '\n';
    }

    // Locking the listener now yields null because s no longer exists.
    std::cout << listeners[0].lock() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Signalled!
<some valid non-null address>
00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.!!I was thinking on similar lines.So I would have to have a vector of pointers to listeners which can be used at the destructor to release or allow for the shared_ptr to do its work. But I don't seem to understand the vector of weak_ptr.

Comment: Those are just the listeners outside the subject - they don't have to be stored in a vector. Note that Subject doesn't need an explicit destructor - when its instance goes out of scope and gets destructed, so does its internal vector and all the shared_ptrs inside it.

Comment: If it's weak_ptr itself you're unfamiliar with, see here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think better to use  boost scoped_connection. This object is designed for things you are looking for.

You can store scoped connections in list for example and when owner of the list will die, the list will call destructors of the scoped connection and one will automatically disconnect your object from the signal slot.

Read details here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/signals2/scoped_connection.html